# problem with 'headers = headers' in web crawling

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am practice my web crawling to get text from website, but I have problem with my 'headers = headers'. when I am run .py, it returns like this:

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'items'
```

my code is as below:

```
import requests
import time
import re


headers = {'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'}

f = open('/Users/pgao/Desktop/doupo.rtf','a+')

def get_info(url):
    res = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        contents = re.findall('<p>(.*?)</p>', res.content.decode('utf-8'),re.S)
        for content in contents:
            f.write(content+'\n')
    else:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ['http://www.doupoxs.com/doupocangqiong/{}.html'.format(str(i)) for i in range(2,10)]
    for url in urls:
        get_info(url)
        time.sleep(1)

f.close()
```

I am struggle with the reason to use 'headers = headers' since some time when web scraping there is no need of it, but sometime it need. and the result where I googled is not that helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header needs to be a `dict` but you created a `set`. The syntax is similar, but notice how the following has a key:value pair

```
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers), `headers` for `requests.get()` must be a `dict`.

> If you’d like to add HTTP headers to a request, simply pass in a `dict` to the headers parameter.

You have passed a `set`. Sets do not have any `items()` method. That is why you are getting this `AttributeError`.

```
headers = {'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36'}

print(type(headers))
# <class 'set'>
```

Add a key to your `headers` variable.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 .....'}
```

Edit: Updated key value for "User-Agent" header.